# How do I stop the speaker from unmuting after wake-up?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, suspend-resume, 9.04

I am using Ubuntu 9.10 Netbook Remix. Some seconds after wake-up, 
the speaker unmutes, even if it was muted before. I'd like to have it muted 
always after suspend.

I created a rule in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` but it doesn't work, probably because it is unmuted after some seconds.

*edit* I have the impression that this gnome soundcontrol does the unmuting, but I am not sure. I looked thru all the gconf but couldn't find an option.

Comment: Funny. I've had the opposite problem where the dang speaker mutes after wakeup. Using alsa-utils to save my settings hasn't worked.

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the gconf-editor, have you tried /apps/indicator-sound/volume_mute

The description says:

> On start up volume should not be muted.

Comment: no i don't have this entry ...should I add? I looked thru the whole gconf for something like mute, already

Comment: Ah. I have this key on 10.10. I guess it appears somewhere between 9.10 and 10.10. Adding it yourself will likely not help.